# Current/power requirements for electric fence?

Tags: batteries

We just ordered some new electric fence chargers for our farm. The new chargers are designed to work off mains or battery. Due to the location, we are considering running off battery with a solar recharger (25w or larger panel) instead of permanently running wire to the nearest fenceline. That would also give us the option to more easily move the charger around and energize different pastures.

I'm hoping someone here could help me understand - I looked for a smaller/lighter battery pack (lithium ion, maybe a small bank of 18650 cells?), but the only batteries I'm finding for electric fences are the larger/heavier lead batteries. Assuming everything was weatherproof, is there something fundamental about current draw or 'rechargability' that would make 18650s undesirable in this type of application? I get they might be a little more expensive, but the trade off for easy portability seems worth it.

I appreciate any insights you can provide!

Comment: You say a little more expensive, but aren't lithium cells a LOT more expensive? I thought they were like...more than quadruple the price.

Comment: All these answers talk about lithium ion batteries. There is a difference in chemistry between lithium ion and lithium iron phosphate.

Answer (score 4):

After having watched this [teardown of an electric fence controller](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2LuWr25xgzE) and listening to [this podcast](https://theamphour.com/481-an-interview-with-paul-thompson/) which is an interview with a designer of electric fence controllers, I think I might have an answer.

The reasons why electric fence controllers mostly use 12 V lead-acid batteries as their power source are:

- low price of these batteries
- easy availability
- can be charged in/from a car
- can be charged using a cheap charger (of a type many farmers will already have).

Li-Ion cells are nowhere near as robust as lead-acid batteries. They require much more delicate charging and handling. A charge controller/balancer is a must-have. A battery protection circuit is also a must-have.

I also think that the electric fence controller manufacturers are quite conservative, if there's no pressing reason to change then they prefer not to. If you watch the video and listen to the podcast I linked above you'll notice how safety and reliability is very important.

Answer (score 1):

Temperature is probably going to be your biggest consideration. LiIon doesn't like high / low temps, even if "weatherproof" you'd need to get a cold rated battery. Otherwise as long as the characteristics of the battery you pick match what the chargers require, there shouldn't be an issue. Yes, there are electrical differences between capabilities of SLA and LiIon but your charger should get what it needs out of either one.

Comment: Lithium is also not as rugged as lead-acid. Lead-acid can tolerate the abuse of simplistic charging methods. Lithium...not so much.

Comment: Yes that would fall under the "Yes, there are electrical differences" comment, but since the asker stated he is using a solar panel, my assumption was that an inverter would be chosen that would support the battery choice. I probably should have said temperature would be your "next" biggest consideration and likely rule out LiIon altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Li-Ion batteries are not supposed to be charged below 0°C, while lead-acid type can be charged down to -20°C. At the upper temperature range their behavior is similar.
 However, since you mentioned using solar panels to charge your batteries, I have to say that Li-Ion is a lot better choice for solar because they don't need a long-term, 3-stage charging method like the lead-acid.
They are also more receptive and thus faster to charge, unlike the lead-acid that needs relatively lower currents (compared to their capacity). This makes them ideal for solar charging because the power could be available for only a short time due to weather or shorter days during winter.
Another plus for them is their charging efficiency which is usually 95% and above, while for lead-acid it is between 80 and 85%.
In order to charge Li-ion batteries, all you need to do is limit their charging current and maximum voltage. A plain CC/CV DC-DC converter will do.
The charging current limit is usually set to no more than 1C (C - charging rate expressed as a fraction of rated capacity in Ah; charging a 1Ah battery at 1A is 1C rate and should take about 1h to charge, while charging the same 1Ah at 0.2A is 0.2C or C/5 rate and would take about 5h to charge).
I would recommend getting higher capacity Li-Ion because it will last you longer and will cover the power needs during very cloudy days when the solar panel output will fall to 3-5% of its rated power.
A Li-Ion battery also definitely has to have a built-in BMS (Battery Management System) which keeps all cells charged equally, and which prevents their overcharge and "over-discharge" (they should never go below 2.5-2.8V).
If you are expecting freezing temperatures, you could bury the Li-Ion battery deep enough to protect it from going below about 2-4°C.
It is possible to charge most Li-Ion batteries below 0°C, but at a VERY low current (0.02C or a 50-hour charging rate).

Answer (score 0):

Lead-acid batteries have a long service life, are inexpensive, and have relatively forgiving charging requirements, and can be designed to be basically maintenance-free. They're also very recyclable, much more so than Li-ion.

It's very hard to make an argument for Li-ion for a fixed application like this, given its expense and fussy charging profile (not to mention its tendency to explode if charged improperly.) I would hate to be the rancher that set off a conflagration due to a Li-ion 'venting' scenario.

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers focus on the technical side, they all miss one obvious point:

The farmers / ranchers are knowledgable about the lead acid batteries,

They have charging equipment and use solar panels,

There is always a suitable battery, or two, on the farm,

So having to go to Li Ion just means more expense - which is not a plus for a farmer...